# What changes must be made in an android app to run only on a specific phone model?

Tags: android

For a android app what changes must be made to run on a specific phone model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure this kind of functionality you can't implement so **you can't restrict your application to a particular brand/model only i.e. you cant allow particular model to have  application in their android market application**

But instead you can restrict your application to the particular screen/density. For that you need to define **`<supports-screen>`** inside the **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

Answer (score 0):

Check for phone model using `Build.MODEL`, if it is the model you want the application to run on, allow the application to run, else close the application